# LNK 2038: RuntimeLibrary mismatch when using #include <xxx>

Tags: c++

so I have C++ code in a dll 'MyDll', which is PInvoked by a C# project. This setup has been working well. Recently I introduced a few instances of #include <> and now, whenever I try to compile in Debug mode, I get the LNK 2038 error:

```
1>SimConnect.lib(SimConnectClient.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in MyDll.obj
1>SimConnect.lib(commClient.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in MyDll.obj
1>SimConnect.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in MyDll.obj
```

SimConnect.lib is a release version (I don't have the source code) and there fore, it's RuntimeLibrary's value is MD (Multit-hreaded DLL (release)). Now, according to several answers on SO I've already found, I changed my RuntimeLibrary to MD in the Debug configuration.

My problem is concretely that, even after changing the RuntimeLibrary on MyDll's project's properties to Multi-threaded Dll (MD) in the Debug configuration, I still get the **exact same errors**. Since I am getting the exact same error, the key part being

"... doesn't match value **'MDd_DynamicDebug'** in MyDll.obj"

even though the project properties have been changed, I take this as a hint that I am probably not changing the RuntimeLibrary's value correctly?

Furthermore, the errors only pop up when I use #include <> (#include "xxx" is not a problem"). Whenever I comment out any #include <> the errors don't trouble me.

Could someone give me a hint about what I might be doing wrong?

It would be also interesting to know why using these #includes trigger the mismatch errors with SimConnect.

Comment: It does not have anything to do with the #include, everything to do with what you link.  Having only one flavor of a static library build available is a serious problem and one you should not put up with.  These kind of problems don't end at the /MD vs /MDd mismatch, it will get worse in the future when you update the VS version that has a new runtime DLL but are still stuck with that old library that requires the old one.  As-is, you didn't seem to successfully have changed the /MD option, ensure the proper configuration and platform are selected, comboboxes at the top of the settings dialog.

Comment: Ok yes, I found a debug flavor for the libraries and I updated them to the latest version and now it all works. Hadn't had that issue before but I'm fairly new to c++.